# mysql stored procedure - validate input xml

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures

I have a mysql 5.1, stored procedure that takes TEXT input which is supposed to contain an XML.

I could successfully parse XML and do everything needed. Now that I am working on error handling part, I need to know how to make sure that the input XML is well formed and valid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything in MySQL's XML support that says "this is well formed XML" but you can fake it. MySQL has an [`ExtractValue`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function:

> `ExtractValue()` takes two string arguments, a fragment of XML markup **`xml_frag`** and an XPath expression **`xpath_expr`** (also known as a ***locator***); it returns the text (CDATA) of the first text node which is a child of the element(s) matched by the XPath expression.

But you can also use this to check the XML since:

> If no matching text node is found for the expression (including the implicit `/text()`)—for whatever reason, as long as **`xpath_expr`** is valid, and **`xml_frag`** consists of elements which are properly nested and closed—an empty string is returned.
>   [...]
>   `NULL` is returned if **`xml_frag`** contains elements which are not properly nested or closed, and a warning is generated...

So if you hand `ExtractValue` any valid XPath expression and any valid piece of XML then you will get a non-NULL result but if you use value XPath and invalid XML, you get a NULL back. So all you need to do is build an INSERT and UPDATE triggers that use `ExtractValue` to check the XML and [`signal`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) to raise an exception if you get a NULL:

```
select ExtractValue(new.your_xml_column, '/*') into @xml_check;
if @xml_check is null then
    signal sqlstate '45000';
end if;
```

Comment: Aaah I have 5.1 and signal does not seem to be available. But I took your advise and just created an error if I did not find one of the mandatory elements.

Comment: @JyotsnaSonawane: I think SIGNAL came in with 5.5, the alternative is to create some other error as you're doing.